# OpenBSD ipsec routing

Tags: routing, openbsd, ipsec

I have an OpenBSD VM that I wish to connect to my OpenBSD home router with ipsec. The objective is to have a secure channel between my home network and the VM.

So I have the following ike conf' on the router :

```
ip_mirror= "212.237.177.102"
ip_dina= "89.234.141.151"

ikev2 'mirror.22decembre.eu' passive esp \
        from 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 to 2a00:5881:8110:2100::/64 \
        from 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 to 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 \
        local 2a06:4000:10::c7 peer 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 \
        dstid dina.22decembre.eu \
        rsa

ikev2 'mirrorv4' passive esp \
        from 10.0.0.0/16 to 10.2.0.0/16 \
        from 10.0.0.0/16 to $ip_dina \
        local $ip_mirror peer $ip_dina \
        dstid dina.22decembre.eu \
        rsa
```

on the VM :

```
ip_dina= "89.234.141.151"
ip_mirror= "212.237.177.102"
ip6_dina="2a00:5881:8110:2100::2"
ip6_mirror="2a06:4000:10::c7"

ikev2 'dina.22decembre.eu' active esp \
        from 2a00:5881:8110:2100::/64 to 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 \
        from  $ip6_dina  to 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 \
        local $ip6_dina peer $ip6_mirror \
        dstid mirror.22decembre.eu \
        rsa

ikev2 'dinav4' active esp \
        from  10.2.0.0/16  to 10.0.0.0/16 \
        from $ip_dina to 10.0.0.0/16 \
        local $ip_dina peer $ip_mirror \
        dstid mirror.22decembre.eu \
        rsa
```

It creates the relevant flows (or so I believe) :

```
stephane@dina:/home/stephane doas ipsecctl -sa
FLOWS:
flow esp in from 10.0.0.0/16 to 10.2.0.0/16 peer 212.237.177.102 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp in from 10.0.0.0/16 to 89.234.141.151 peer 212.237.177.102 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp out from 10.2.0.0/16 to 10.0.0.0/16 peer 212.237.177.102 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp out from 89.234.141.151 to 10.0.0.0/16 peer 212.237.177.102 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp in from 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 to 2a00:5881:8110:2100::/64 peer 2a06:4000:10::c7 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp in from 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 to 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 peer 2a06:4000:10::c7 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp out from 2a00:5881:8110:2100::/64 to 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 peer 2a06:4000:10::c7 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require
flow esp out from 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 to 2a06:4001:c7:e2::/64 peer 2a06:4000:10::c7 srcid FQDN/dina.22decembre.eu dstid FQDN/mirror.22decembre.eu type require

SAD:
esp tunnel from 89.234.141.151 to 212.237.177.102 spi 0x4fb1aa68 auth hmac-sha2-256 enc aes-256
esp tunnel from 2a06:4000:10::c7 to 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 spi 0x9589f762 auth hmac-sha2-256 enc aes-256
esp tunnel from 212.237.177.102 to 89.234.141.151 spi 0xb54032ea auth hmac-sha2-256 enc aes-256
esp tunnel from 2a00:5881:8110:2100::2 to 2a06:4000:10::c7 spi 0xce462a4c auth hmac-sha2-256 enc aes-256
```

I can even ping the home server (or ssh it) on its private address from the VM :

```
stephane@dina:/home/stephane ping 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=27.239 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=27.415 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=27.270 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 27.239/27.308/27.415/0.077 ms
```

But other traffic does not go through so easily (no syslog for example).

I wonder what I did wrong, I went through OpenBSD's FAQ several times and I don't see my mistake.

Can you help me solve that ?

Comment: I have the same problem using tcpdump I can see that big packets do not get ack'ed with multiple ack in tcpdump.